# How to create a PHP app that allows user to have custom fields

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any sample PHP app out there that allows user to set up custom fields?

Such as an address book, etc. Such as setting a field as Home, Home Away, etc without database columns in mySQL. Being able to have as many fields as they want and naming it however they want.

So result might be:

```
| #   | Name  | DOB    | Address 1     | Health  
| 1   | Scott | 7/1/12 | 2222 Jackson  |  GOOD
```

Another set of data might be

```
| # | Name  | Expertise Level | Contact Info    
| 1 | Scott | High            | 408-555-5555
```

I'm curious as how that would be done. Would everything be stored as JSON in single mysql table? And how would data for each field be stored?

Any PHP script out there that already does this so I can just take it apart to understand?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you have this tagged with MySQL there are ways that you can have a flexible database table. You can create a table that contains Name-Value-Pairs similar to this:

```
create table YourTable
(
  id int,
  name varchar(50),
  attribute varchar(50),
  value varchar(50)
);

insert into yourtable
values(1, 'Scott', 'DOB', '07/01/2012'),
  (1, 'Scott', 'Address 1', '2222 Jackson'),
  (1, 'Scott', 'Health', 'Good'),
  (1, 'Scott', 'Expertise Level', 'High'),
  (1, 'Scott', 'Contact Info', '408-555-5555');
```

This is also known an `Entity-Attribute-Value`. There are positives and negatives to using this type of structure.

In order to query this data, you have to either perform multiple joins or you can *pivot* the data to get it into columns.

Here is an [question on DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/is-there-a-name-for-this-database-structure) that outlines this type of structure (EAV).

You can query the data using an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
select id,
  name,
  max(case when attribute = 'DOB' then value end) DOB,
  max(case when attribute = 'Address 1' then value end) Address1,
  max(case when attribute = 'Health' then value end) Health
from yourtable
group by id, name;
```

If you wanted to perform multiple joins, then the query would be similar to this:

```
select t1.id,
  t1.name,
  t1.value DOB,
  t2.value Address1,
  t3.value Health
from yourtable t1
left join yourtable t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
  and t1.name = t2.name
  and t2.attribute='Address 1'
left join yourtable t3
  on t1.id = t3.id
  and t1.name = t3.name
  and t3.attribute='Health'
where t1.attribute = 'DOB';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4c80/4) of data retrieval.

Comment: Would need primary key with id, name, and attribute.

Comment: He asked for something that's not using database

Comment: @datasage yes, you would need a primary key. This is just a sample

Comment: @VoitekZylinski I am showing alternative version where you could use a database to store the data.  As this is tagged with both MySQL and PHP. Thanks for the downvote though

Comment: @VoitekZylinski I took it to mean that he didn't want an additional column for each attribute, perhaps bluefeet did too?  What was the intention ScottYu?

Comment: Perhaps you're right. Up voted.

Comment: @AllInOne Yes intention was no additional column for each attribute. I am okay with using database.

Comment: What is the performance of something like this compared to provision fields for custom fields (which does create limit of how many custom fields they can do). Would queries be fairly fast using this system?

Comment: @ScottYu-UXdesigner as long as you have correct indexes ¥ou should not have any issues with performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can always have a table with columns that are common between your objects. like `ID` and `Name` in your example. also an additional column called `Data` that you store the rest of the  `custom fields` of each object in it. It can be stored in `json`, `xml` or as a `serialized php object`.

you can take a look at php [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)  and [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) functions.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do custom fields. Each with their pros and cons.

Serializing is generally not recommended. While it sometimes has its uses, you lose much of what makes relational data relational. You wont have any effective way of indexing or searching on a specific field either.

Making all data fields relational can create very complicated queries/joins to access the data when you need it.

Using MongoDB may be an option. You could create a unique collection for each data set and add appropriate indexes to each set. Its schema-less do you wont have to do any table creation. Just insert data. You do want to take time to understand its limitations however.

Another option might be, depending on your datasets, is to provision fields used for custom data, while common fields will be part of a normal row. You would be limited on the number of custom fields you could offer though.